Creating a new object with properties in a given ordinal order
I have a function, it takes an object that has bunch of properties and eventually it creates a new object from that input object. I pass a dictionary for field-mapping to it to tell the function what property of the input object should be mapped and renamed to what property name of the new resulting object. So for example input object can have twenty properties but I might be only interested in having a new object with five properties and new names for those properties so this way I will have a map with five properties in it.
My function works and you are more than welcome to make it better or more efficient too.
But my main question is why the order of properties in the result is not the same as the order of keys of my field-map dictionary.
Here is the code and data to recreate it:
function Convert-APIObjectToCustomObject {
    param (
        [Array]$dataFromAPI,
        [Hashtable]$fieldMap
    )

    $resultData = @()    

    foreach ($item in $dataFromAPI) {
        $newObject = New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject

        foreach ($key in $fieldMap.Keys) {
            $matchedProperty = $item.PSObject.Properties | Where-Object { $_.Name.ToLower() -eq $fieldMap[$key].ToLower() }
            if ($matchedProperty) {
                $propertyValue = $matchedProperty.Value
            } else {
                Write-Warning "Property '$($fieldMap[$key])' not found on the input object. Setting default value."
                $propertyValue = $null  # or you can set it to '' for an empty string
            }

            $newObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $key -Value $propertyValue
        }
        $resultData += $newObject
    }
    return $resultData
}

# Example usage:
$dataFromAPI = @(
    [PSCustomObject]@{ InstrumentId='1'; ServiceLayer='Service1'; MaturityDate=1; Gheimat='5' ; ExtraCol = '45' },
    [PSCustomObject]@{ InstrumentId='2'; ServiceLayer='Service2'; MaturityDate=2; Gheimat='17'; ExtraCol = '1000'},
    [PSCustomObject]@{ InstrumentId='3'; ServiceLayer='Service1'; MaturityDate=1; Gheimat='3' ; ExtraCol = 'Hi'},
    [PSCustomObject]@{ InstrumentId='4'; ServiceLayer='Service1'; MaturityDate=1; Gheimat='7' ; ExtraCol = 'Hello' }
)

$fieldsMap = @{
    "Id" = "InstrumentId"
    "Service" = "ServiceLayer"
    "Propertyx" = "MaturityDate"
    "Price" = "Gheimat"
}

$resultData2 = Convert-APIObjectToCustomObject -dataFromAPI $dataFromAPI -fieldMap $fieldsMap

so I want the order of properties appearing on my result be the same as the order of "keys" I have defined in my fieldMap.  But currently it is not.  How can I do that?

fieldMap is a hashtable in your current example, key order isn't ensured in a hashtable.

Issue with your code is the variable $fieldMap being a Hashtable instead of an OrderedDictionary. Next issue is parameter -fieldMap typed as Hashtable instead of IDictionary or OrderedDictionary.
As for making your code more efficient, you can use .PSObject.Properties to reflect on the properties of your $item in the loop. You can also, again, use an OrderedDictionary to construct the new object and later on cast it to the [pscustomobject] type accelerator. This improves your code efficiency by great amount, Add-Member is very slow compared to this technique. See script-authoring-considerations#use-ordereddictionary-to-dynamically-create-new-objects for more details.
Lastly, you can stream objects from your function, there is no need to += to the array. Also very inefficient, see script-authoring-considerations#array-addition.
Summarizing (using the same $dataFromAPI than in your question for shorter code):
function Convert-APIObjectToCustomObject {
    param (
        [Array] $dataFromAPI,
        [System.Collections.IDictionary] $fieldMap
    )

    foreach ($item in $dataFromAPI) {
        $newObject = [ordered]@{}
        $reflectedProperties = $item.PSObject.Properties

        foreach ($key in $fieldMap.Keys) {
            $matchedProperty = $reflectedProperties[$fieldMap[$key]]

            if ($matchedProperty) {
                $propertyValue = $matchedProperty.Value
            }
            else {
                Write-Warning "Property '$($fieldMap[$key])' not found on the input object. Setting default value."
                $propertyValue = $null  # or you can set it to '' for an empty string
            }

            $newObject[$key] = $propertyValue
        }

        [pscustomobject] $newObject
    }
}

$dataFromAPI = @( 
    # same as before
)

$fieldsMap = [ordered]@{
    'Id'        = 'InstrumentId'
    'Service'   = 'ServiceLayer'
    'Propertyx' = 'MaturityDate'
    'Price'     = 'Gheimat'
}

Convert-APIObjectToCustomObject -dataFromAPI $dataFromAPI -fieldMap $fieldsMap

